# Find a parametric equation to solve a line integral

Tags: line-integrals, parametrization

Find

$ \int_C \frac{dz}{z} $ from $1 - 5i$ to $5 + 6i$

I want to use 
$$\int_C f(Z) dz = \int_a^b f[z(t)]z'(t)dt$$

My guess is that I need to find $z(t)$ such that 
$$z(a) = 1 - 5i$$
$$z(b) = 5 + 6i$$

But how?

Comment: I would select such a path connecting the two points that the function $1/z$ has an anti-derivative in some open set containing my path. Different choices will lead to different results, so...

Answer (score 2):

I found a displacement vector $<4, 11>$ such that $<1, -5> + <4, 11> = <5, 6>$

Now I can define a parametric line in terms of these vectors $<1, -5> + t<4, 11> = <1 + 4t, -5 + 11t>$ which is equivalent to :

$$z(t) = 1 + 5t + i(-5 + 11t)$$
$$0 \leq t \leq 1$$

since

$$z(0) = 1 - 5i$$
$$z(1) = 5 + 6i$$

Then we deal with the integral:

$$\int_c \frac{1}{z} = \int_0^1 \frac{4 + 11i}{1 - 5i + t\left(4 + 11i\right)}dt  \hspace{1cm} 0 \leq t \leq 1$$

which gives the result

$$ln|5 + 6i| - ln|1 - 5i|$$

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use any path from $a$ to $b$.  You should get the same answer as long as the path does not include the origin.  This is the Principle of Path Independence.  It follows from the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem.

Comment: It isn't that simple. Surely the answer depends on which way you go around the origin.

Comment: Sorry.  I should have been more specific.  What I said is true provided the path is contained in a simply connected domain and the integrand is analytic in the domain.  Here the only problem point is the origin, so you should get the same answer as long as the path is contained in a simply connected domain which does not include the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$$z(t)=(b-a)t+a$$ $$  t\in [0,1]$$

So $$z(0)=a$$

$$z(1)=b$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your answer is equal $ln|b| - ln|a|$.  Since the integrand $\frac{1}{z}$ is continuous everywhere except $0$ and the path doesn't go near $0$ you can get the same answer using the Fundamental Theorem for Line Integrals.